# Gel in water machine

Tags: everyday-chemistry, water

I have a hot and cold water dispensing machine from my water company. I use 5 gallon water jugs delivered ever 3-4 weeks. The machine has a tank in it where water is kept cold until dispensed by gravity into whatever container I choose to use.

In the bottom of the tank I found a gelatin looking liquid in the bottom.  There was also ice formed where that tank is cooled. My company says its from the hot part of the machine heating water then the cool part cooling it causing the minerals to separate and not dissolve back into the water. I have never seen gelatin minerals before but wondered it this is something I need to look into further.

[image: gelatin substance from bottom of water machine]